# How can I fix HTTP error 400 in this python code?

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to scrap a post from Facebook. Keeps returning HTTP error 400. Any clues?

Here are my codes:

```
try:
    req=urllib.request.Request(url)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        the_page=response.read()
    if response.getcode()==200:
        data=json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        print(data)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

and error is as below:

```
>>> response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Users\sknkuh10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\sknkuh10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\sknkuh10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\sknkuh10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sknkuh10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sknkuh10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
>>>
```

Comment: Are you using Facebook graph API? Post your url (no need the accessToken), thats may be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error happens when something in your request doesn't match the server's expectations. For example it may be due to:

- **Are you setting the `Content-Type` header?** Normally it's `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for an API call, but there are other possibilities.
- **Are you using the correct HTTP method?** An error in the method can cause an error 400 or 405. In your code I see you are sending a `GET`, ensure that API expects a GET and not a `POST` or `PUT` requests.
- **Are you sending the correct body?** This doesn't apply for `GET` (usually) but if you are sending a `POST` or `PUT` then an error in the data you send can cause an error 400 in the server.
- **Any other required header you are missing?** If you are copying the request from the browser, the easiest way to know if you are sending all the headers is to right click the request in DevTools and selecting `Copy as Curl`.

I find easier to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine. See the example below.

```
import urllib.request

try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url="https://www.google.com")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    status_code = response.getcode()
    print("returned {} status code".format(status_code))
    
    if status_code == 200:
        charset = response.info().get_content_charset()
        content = response.read().decode(charset)
    else:
       #do something
       pass
   
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Citing the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1):

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Thus, I would say that the error relies in the url of your request.